# PHP Validating relative path for files manager

Tags: php, angularjs, validation, symfony

I have built media manager with Symfony + Angular but need to make it super secure so that user won't be able to remove files outside of base directory, won't be able to upload files anywhere else, won't be able to crash system by trying to make some wierd file name.

So far my function looks like this:

```
protected function validatePath($path)
{
    return !(strpos($path, '..') !== false || strpos($path, $this->baseDir) !== 0 || empty($path));
}
```

But I think it's not enough. **I don't need to correct this path.** If it is invalid i simply throw error. I will need some kind of preg_math to check for invalid chars and maybe check if each of the parts is not too long. What do you guys think? What should I check to test if path is valid? Manager is admin only but you never know. So far user is able to:

1. Create catalogs
2. Upload files
3. Remove files
4. Edit text files
5. Rename files

So path is validated on `unlink` `mkdir` `move` etc. I've read similar posts but there is one difference here, i don't need to replace `realpath` with `truepath` nor i don't want to correct paths. I also don't want to validate windows paths (since unix directory separator works on windows).

In my case path is valid if:

- it is inside media base directory
- only goes forward (no .. allowed)
- is not empty
- may or may not exist (so realpath is not an option)
- directory separators are unix /
- it is relative
- it is not too long (I don't know how to properly check this one)
- it does not contain invalid chars (could use help with this one)

Thanks in advance.